# Having trouble getting div to stretch to footer in Wordpress

Tags: css

site is www.greenaustralia.net.au

Underneath the slideshow I have the div area which houses 4 seperate div layers which are already inline. I'm having trouble getting the parent div to stretch down to the bottom of the page.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

```
.site-extra {
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
background: #CCD1B6;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the:

```
<div id="extra" class="container site-extra extra-four"></div>
```

Inside of your footer tag

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div id="extra" class="container site-extra extra-four">...</div>
    <div class="clearfix container">
    ....
    </div>
</footer>
```

Hope this help

Comment: They are in seperate PHP files.

Comment: well, this is a "hack fix" but should work... in your css add - .site-extra { position: fixed; }

Comment: @IOne Liccy yes this works. Perfect, cant believe I missed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add position: absolute; to your extra_site css class